# How to Change the database structure in Mongodb using Javascript?

Tags: mongodb

How to change the structure of the database in Mongodb using java scripts? For example how to change the field "tax": "value" into embedded document like `"tax" : {"serviceTaxAmount" : 1746,"serviceTax" : 14, "sbcTax" : 0.5,"sbcTaxAmount" : 0.5 % of grandAmount}` for the documents having the "date" field and that date field should be greater than 15-Sep-2015.

Comment: can u post a sample document and the result that you are expecting?

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing that you want to insert a structured data, if so you just insert an object of objects like the below example

```
var tax = {
        "serviceTaxAmount" : 1746,
        "serviceTax" : 14, 
        "sbcTax" : 0.5,
        "sbcTaxAmount" : 0.5 % of grandAmount
    }

var payment = {
    amount: 10000,
    tax : tax
}

db.order.insert(payment);
```

Hope I am right, if not let me know what exactly you were looking for.